# offset with column=-1 in VBA

Tags: vba, offset

I'm trying to find a solution to the problem when selecting a column =-1
first I select the cell `A1`, and then I apply this code.

```
 Sub exc()
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
If .Offset(-1, 0).Row < 1 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
End Sub
```

But problem not solved.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test before doing the offset:

```
Sub exc()
IF Activecell.Row > 1 then
     ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
End Sub
```